# How to upload data from previous year if this year's data is unavailable

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

TABLE : TEST

```
Batch   Year    Value
----------------------
A   2014    11
A   2015    0
A   2016    22
A   2017    0
A   2018    13
B   2015    10
B   2016    0
B   2017    29
B   2018    0
C   2013    24
C   2014    0
D   2015    27
D   2016    0
```

Herein batchwise suppose data is not there in 2015 it should take data from 2014, similarly if data is unavailable in a particular year for a particular batch then data from the previous year should be allocated to that year.

I tried to put case statement by taking only batch A but the problem is that my query is showing subquery return multiple rows.

```
SELECT BATCH, YEAR,
(CASE WHEN VALUE = 0 THEN
(SELECT A.VALUE FROM TEST A, TEST B WHERE A.YEAR = B.YEAR-1 AND A.VALUE <> '0') ELSE VALUE END)
FROM TEST;
```

Required Output table:

Test

```
Batch   Year    Value
---------------------
A   2014    11
A   2015    11
A   2016    22
A   2017    22
A   2018    13
B   2015    10
B   2016    10
B   2017    29
B   2018    29
C   2013    24
C   2014    24
D   2015    27
D   2016    27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below query to achieve your result,

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1(Batch VARCHAR(10), Year INT, Value INT)
INSERT INTO TEST1
VALUES('A', 2014,11),
('A', 2015,0 ),
('A', 2016,22),
('A', 2017,0 ),
('A', 2018,13),
('B', 2015,10),
('B', 2016,0 ),
('B', 2017,29),
('B', 2018,0 ),
('C', 2013,24),
('C', 2014,0 ),
('D', 2015,27),
('D', 2016,0 )

SELECT batch, year, CASE WHEN value = 0  then LAG(value) OVER(PARTITION BY batch ORDER BY year) ELSE value END AS value
FROM TEST1
ORDER BY batch, year
```